# Is it possible to generate TypeScript Type Definition/Declaration files?

Tags: typescript, svelte

So far I've tried to configure it in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",

  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir" : "public/lib" 
  }
}
```

and in the `rollup.config.js`

```js
...
output: {
  sourcemap: true,
  format: 'iife',
  name: 'app',
  dir: 'public/lib',
},
...
typescript({ sourceMap: !production, declaration: true, declarationDir: 'public/lib' }),
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

if you need to create global types, you can just create an `index.d.ts` file in your src folder (for example) and the types you add in this file will be available in your whole project, you don't need to do any other thing.

Comment: that is true, but I would like to generate it based on the component.
for example `UserComponent.svelte` => `UserComponent.d.ts`